# Redirect all subdomains using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

What I want to achieve is to redirect any subdomain.mydomain.info to mydomain.info/subdomain using a 301 so that the visitor still sees subdomain.mydomain.info.

After some research I found that I had to set wildcard in my A-Record, did that. Than I went on to create a .htaccess. Below is my entire .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.info [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.domain\.info [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

When I open subdomain.mydomain.info where I know that mydomain.info/subdomain is an existing folder I only get a message telling me that the domain "subdomain.mydomain.info" is unavailable.

My webspace is running a Confixx panel, just if that helps.

What could be going wrong here?
At this point I am guessing that some configuration outside the .htacces need to be made, but no idea what and where.

**BIG EDIT:**

Revisiting this. Turned out I had to talk to my provider to get some things set up correctly. Still trying to figure this our though.

Current situation: the .htaccess from above gives me a 500. Putting in an R, als was suggested in the comments, will redirect "sd.domain.info" to "domain.info/sd/sd/sd/sd" and result in an error by my browser. The browser says "There is redirect on this page" and give me the option to load it again. The version suggested by Al Kafri Firas also gives me a 500. When I remove the .htaccess any "subdomain.doamin.info" gets redirected to "domain.info" with the URL being changed in the head of my browser.

Still looking to get this working....

Comment: Are you able to ping `subdomain.mydomain.info`?

Comment: Yes I am and it resolves to the same IP as domain.info.

Comment: So you are no longer getting `domain "subdomain.mydomain.info" is unavailable` error?

Comment: I do get that when visiting the website with a browser, ping from console works fine though. Confusing part is that the title of the tab says "Confixx" which is the backend software to manage the domain. And it's not the browser telling me the site can't be reached, I get a website telling me the domain is unavailable.

Comment: Can you run `telnet subdomain.domain.info 80` and see if you can connect.

Comment: It says "connected" guessing that mean I can connect.

Comment: Add an `R` in above rule and then do test as `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L,R]`

Comment: Tried. Didn't change anything.

Comment: What URL did you get in your browser?

Comment: I am visiting subdomain.domain.info and I get to a site that tells me "subdomain.domain.info" is unavailable. Maybe this helps? http://forum.l4u.info/ that's the site I am trying to get to work.

Comment: It doesn't look your above rule is even firing. Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: Hmm this is weird. When I visit "subdomain.domain.info" I get the same things as before. But when I visit "domain.info" I get a 500 Internal Server Error. Don't know what to make of this.

Comment: That means `subdomain.domain.info` is going to different `DocumentRoot`. Can you show how `subdomain.domain.info` is setup in Apache?

Comment: Sounds plausible. Don't think I can show you how it's set up. I just have a webspace and a website to make adjustments. Don't run the Apache myself. Is there any php script or anything i could run to get the needed information?

Comment: Create a file called `info.php` with this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then open `http://subdomain.domain.com/info.php` to check what is its `DOCUMENT_ROOT` value.

Comment: The root resolves to "/var/www/web[my account number]/html/l4u". But that's from domain.info/subdomain since subdomain.domain.info only gives me an error. Does this help?

Comment: Move this .htaccess to something else and then revisit `subdomain.domain.info` to see what you get. If you still get an error then you need to ask your admin to get this right in Apache config

Comment: Still get the same.. guess I will talk to my admins. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Yes there is nothing rewrite rules can do since you have moved .htaccess itself

Answer (score 0):

Revert all changes you made to your A-Record and use this rules

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.info$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.example\.info$ [NC]
RewriteRule /%2%{REQUEST_URI} [PT,L]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. Tried that. Actually had not made changes to my A-Record, wildcard was already set. Still not working for me though.

Comment: After removing the wildcard I just get my browser telling me it can't reach the site and no longer a "domain unavailable".